# Border around image in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

How to have a black border around image in c#.the image exists inside a wrap panel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add a border to the Image:

```
<toolkit:WrapPanel x:Name="wp">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5" >
        <Image Source="myimage.png" />
    </Border>
</toolkit:WrapPanel>
```

Or add it to the WrapPanel in code:

```
var b = new Border
            {
                BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(5)
            };

var bi = new BitmapImage
                {
                    UriSource = new Uri("/myimage.png", UriKind.Relative)
                };

b.Child = new Image {Source = bi};

wp.Children.Add(b);
```

Comment: thanx for the reply..but i am adding image to wrap panel programatically.How can i add border programatically?

Comment: @Shaireen updated answer with example to show adding a bordered image programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use a border element and configure it and set the background to a imagebrush with your image as source.

Here´s some XAML:

```
    <Border BorderBrush="Black">
      <Border.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="<Your Image>"/>
      </Border.Background>
    </Border>
```

You can also define a CornerRadius on the Border to make rounded corners. This will also apply to the image.